# Как вывести 404 страницу по определенному адресу?

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, error404

Есть сайт на **wordpress**.

Как сделать сделать так, чтобы любая ошибочная страница вела по пути *сайт/error/404* и выводился шаблон **404.php** (лежит в корне сайта)?

Делаю вот так, но не работает как ожидал, адрес прописывается верный, но сам шаблон не подтягивается

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', '404_error_redirect' );
function 404_error_redirect()
{
    if( is_404())
    {
        wp_redirect( home_url( '/error/404' ) );
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: прям-вот сейчас хотел написать такой-же вопрос)

Comment: @Антон плюсовать вопрос тогда надо

Comment: @KAGGDesign я исчерпал лимит голосований на сегодня; в следующий раз можно будет проголосовать через 9 часов. Я кстати написал про это на мете тут: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10592/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2?noredirect=1#comment44710_10592

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот исправленный и протестированный код из ответа WP Punk.

```
function my_404_for_page() {
    if ( ! is_404() ) {
        return;
    }

    $request_uri = isset( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) ? filter_var( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ) : '';

    if ( '/error/404' === $request_uri ) {
        get_header();
        require_once ABSPATH . '404.php';
        get_footer();
        exit();
    }

    wp_safe_redirect( home_url( '/error/404' ) );
    exit();
}

add_action( 'wp', 'my_404_for_page' );
```

Comment: спасибо большое! Единственное, в моем случае сработало по такому адресу `require_once get_stylesheet_directory(). '/404.php'; `

Comment: В потому что вопрос сформулирован неверно. В вопросе как написано - в корне сайта. Корень сайта - это там, где wp-config.php. А в комментарии указан путь до корня темы: `/wp-content/themes/my-theme`

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно добавить хук на `wp` и изменить стандартное поведение. Редиректите все страницы на нужную вам, а если это нужная вам, то отдаете 404. Код примерно такой:

```
function my_404_for_page() {
    if ( ! is_404() ) {
        return;
    }
    global $wp_query;
    if ( '/error/404' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) {
        $wp_query->set_404();
        status_header( 404 );
    }
    wp_redirect( home_url( '/error/404' ) );
    exit();
}

add_action( 'wp', 'my_404_for_page' );
```

Comment: Не, "примерно" - это не ответ. Ты код доработай и протестируй. Как код подхватит его файл 404.php, который лежит в корне? Кроме того, я вижу тут бесконечный редирект.

Comment: @WP Punk спасибо, но я и хука  `wp` такого не знаю

Comment: @Вася а зря. Хук такой есть )

Comment: Протестировал твой код - да, бесконечный редирект и не подхватывается 404.php из корня сайта. Ты пропал куда-то, я поместил свой ответ на основе твоего ))